# Instagram API web crawler get all posts for a tag

Tags: api, pagination, web-crawler, instagram

I want to find all the posts tagged with a keyword such as 'starbucks'

Is that possible using the v1/tags/starbucks/media/recent API for this? What does recent mean? If I keep paginating through the posts using next_url or max_tag_id, will I get all the starbucks-related posts? Or does it cut off at a certain date?

There's a total greater than 4 million according to this api.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/starbucks?access_token=x

Thanks!